# Understanding Postgres's similarity algorithm

Tags: postgresql, functions, pattern-matching, string-searching

Could someone explain how [Postgres's similarity algorithm](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html) works?

Why do these examples return different results?

```
select similarity('Foo Bar Baz', 'Foo Bar'); -- 0.8
select similarity('Foo Bar Baz', 'Bar Foo'); -- 0.8
select similarity('Foo Bar Baz', 'Foo Baz'); -- 0.8
select similarity('Foo Bar Baz', 'Baz Foo'); -- 0.8
select similarity('Foo Bar Baz', 'Bar Baz'); -- 0.6
select similarity('Foo Bar Baz', 'Baz Bar'); -- 0.6
```

Comment: You can always read [the source code](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/contrib/pg_trgm/trgm_op.c)

Answer (score 1):

`Bar` and `Baz` differ by only one letter, whereas `Foo` differs from both  `Bar` and `Baz` by all 3 letters.

So it makes sense that when checking the similarity of random 2-word permutations, swapping `Bar` and `Baz`  shouldn't make a big difference, whereas swapping `Foo` with one or `Bar` or `Baz` should make a big difference since `Foo` doesn't share any common letter with these words.

This is why in your results, the 4 permutations that include `Foo` have a stronger similarity with `Foo Bar Baz` than the 2 others that don't include `Foo`.

It should be noted that `pg_trm` does not care about word boundaries.
As they are lined up, the examples provided in the question could make you believe that a similarity of `0.8` means that one 3-letter word out of 3 is missing, but that's not how it works with trigrams.

This query might help to visualize how strings 1-4 are closer to `Foo Bar Baz` than strings 5-6:

```
with l(term) as (values
('Foo Bar Baz')    -- reference
('Foo Bar'),       -- your examples
('Bar Foo'),
('Foo Baz'),
('Baz Foo'),
('Bar Baz'),
('Baz Bar')
)
select term,show_trgm(term) from l;
```

Result:

```
    term     |                        show_trgm                        
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------
 Foo Bar Baz | {"  b","  f"," ba"," fo","ar ","az ",bar,baz,foo,"oo "}
 Foo Bar     | {"  b","  f"," ba"," fo","ar ",bar,foo,"oo "}
 Bar Foo     | {"  b","  f"," ba"," fo","ar ",bar,foo,"oo "}
 Foo Baz     | {"  b","  f"," ba"," fo","az ",baz,foo,"oo "}
 Baz Foo     | {"  b","  f"," ba"," fo","az ",baz,foo,"oo "}
 Bar Baz     | {"  b"," ba","ar ","az ",bar,baz}
 Baz Bar     | {"  b"," ba","ar ","az ",bar,baz}
```